# inserting multiples values in one column

Tags: sql

I have a question about SQL. I have created a table in SQL with only one column containing the name of two people (say John and Matt). Later I added a new column into the table with ALTER TABLE. This column will contain the surname of these people.

My question is, in case mmy table contained several people already is there a command to enter the surnames for all the people at once rather than writing one command for each person as in:

`INSERT INTO table (Surname) VALUE (John's surname)` and

`INSERT INTO table (Surname) VALUE (Matt's surname)` ?

Thanks in advance

P.D.
I tried something like:
UPDATE foo set Surname=("Parker","Walker") where Name =("John","Matt") but does not work

Comment: Use `UPDATE` to update existing rows. E.g. `UPDATE persons SET surname = 'Henderson' WHERE firstname = 'Matt'`.

Comment: @jarlh. Yes, I know how to do it with one person at a time, but the question is how do you update several rows simultaneously?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want an `update`.  Something like this:

```
update t
    set surname = 'John'' surname'
    where firstname = 'John';
```

You can do this separately for each name.  Or use a `case` expression for multiple ones:

```
UPDATE foo
    SET Surname = (CASE WHEN Name = 'John' THEN 'Parker'
                        WHEN Name = 'Matt' THEN 'Walker'
                   END)
    WHERE Name IN ('John', 'Matt');
```